# Drawing a simple Column using css

Tags: html, css

I've been trying to develop a simple page in order to try HTML/CSS and I'm trying to draw a colored column on the left side of the page using CSS. This is how I'm attempting  to make it work:

```
#leftcolumn {
   margin-top: 0px;
   margin-bottom: 0px;
   top: 0px;
   left: 0px;
   width: 60px;
   height: 100%;
   background-color: #276E55;
   float: left;
}
```

And this is what I write on the HTML file:

```
<body>
   <div class="leftcolumn"></div>
   <!--rest of the code here-->
</body>
```

I'm assuming that since I set the column to float left, anything after it will automatically go to the space at the right of it. Also I'm setting the top and bottom margin because the document have a margin to keep the text from reaching the extremities of the page.

I'm assuming I'm doing something wrong regarding it, but I really don't know what am I missing here.

Comment: `height:100%` is going to be the problem here, as floated elements dont inherit the height of their containers, rather from their content, if you have no content inside the column you'll get no height. Is the intention to ever fill it with content? or just to have it be a coloured area on the screen?

Comment: what part is not working?

Comment: `but I really don't know what am I missing here` Neither do we. Describe your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`height` is always based on the parents height, which is unspecified in this case. You have to use a fixed height to make the content visible. Furtermore you are using `class` but referencing the `id` (with `#`). Use `.leftcolum` instead.

Your `left` and `top` is not needed since you are not using `position`.

**Update**
To actually scale the div to 100% height you need as I specified a parent with a certain height.
You can achieve that by scaling the html and body to 100%.

```
html, body{
    height:100%;
}
```

Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/56b77g7t/1/

Comment: I tried what you and @spooky suggested and it worked. Which is a shame, because I really wanted to fill the wholepage vertically without a fixed value.

Comment: @HianNeiva if you're intention is to fill the left area of the screen, have a look at something like this http://jsfiddle.net/56b77g7t/2/

Answer (score 1):

CSS notation is wrong... use . instead of #... and change height into pixels.. see demo below.

```
.leftcolumn {
   margin-top: 0px;
   margin-bottom: 0px;
   top: 0px;
   left: 0px;
   width: 60px;
   height: 900px;
   background-color: #276E55;
   float: left;
}
```

Click here to see the demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/fyee5nm8/1/

Answer (score -1):

You are using class but your CSS is using an id (#) try changing the # for a dot (.)

Comment: Post this as a comment and not an answer.

Comment: I couldnt comment thats why I used an answer :(